# What grade do I need on the final to get an A in the class (if it is even possible)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

So here is the class breakdown (an A is 90%):

> 5% Classwork
>
> 15% Homework
>
> 20% Mean Quiz Score
>
> 15% Test 1
>
> 15% Test 2
>
> 15% Test 3
>
> 15% Final Exam

And there is a catch, which is why I need help figuring this out: The grade you get on your final exam will replace your lowest test score (if it benefits you).

So here are my scores:

5% ---- Classwork: 250/250 points

15% ----  Homework: 2,350/2,350 points

20% ----  Mean Quiz Score: 80/80 points

13.2% ----  Test 1: 88/100 points

7.845% -- Test 2: 34/65 (lol I have a good excuse for this)

13.5% --- Test 3: 90/100

Final: Not yet taken (accounts for 15%)

So the grade I get on the final, assuming it is beneficial for me, will count for 15% of my grade AND it will replace the grade of my lowest test score (test 2). So for example: If I get 13% on the final, the grade for test two will increase to 13% as well.

So my question is, what is the minimum grade that I need to get on the final so that I can get an A in the class?

Would it be 11.7%?

Comment: Would it be 11.7%?

Comment: What percentage do you need for an A? Is it 90%, 89.5%, or something else?

Comment: Oh yeah A is 90%, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get below a 34/65 on the final, then you can easily check that you'll end up with at most an 82.392% in the class.

If you get above a 34/65 on the final, then Test 2 will be worth 0% of your grade and the final will be worth 15%+15% = 30% of your grade.

So, in this case, your grade will be:

$5 \cdot \dfrac{250}{250} + 15 \cdot \dfrac{2350}{2350} + 20 \cdot \dfrac{80}{80} + 15 \cdot \dfrac{88}{100} + 0 \cdot \dfrac{34}{65} + 15 \cdot \dfrac{90}{100} + 30 \cdot x$

where $x$ is your grade on the final. Now, simply set this equal to $90$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: If I get above 34/65 on the final, that score will replace the test 2. For example, if I get 50/65 on the final, my grade for the final is 50/65, and my grade for test 2 changes from 34/65 to 50/65 as well.

Comment: ^Yes, that's why in the case where $x > \tfrac{34}{65}$, test 2 accounts for  $0\%$ of your grade and the final counts for $15\%+15\% = 30\%$ of your grade.

Comment: oh wait I think I see what you did. you removed the score for test two and doubled the score for the final

Comment: So 77.6% on the final... hmmm shouldn't be too hard. Hopefully I get the A. Thank you for the help :)

Comment: ^That's what I got as well. BTW: What class is this?

Comment: It's pre-calculus @college. I'm taking it this summer, 6 weeks of hell (we finished the entire book in 6 weeks)

Comment: @TheNewGuy Even if it looks like 77.6% is easy, you should still pretend that you need an 85% or higher while studying. Aim higher than you need, because this way, if you don't meet your goal, it's not too bad.

Comment: @columbus8myhw yup haha that's what I like to do !